# Complex LINQ on DataRow

Tags: c#, linq

not sure if this is possible, but I have a DataRow `row` and I want to retrieve a string array of all values where the column name begins "FK".

Is this doable or am I asking to much of LINQ?

Comment: Your take crashes if at least one of values is not a string but something else (an int maybe). Using `ToString` or `Convert.ToString` as shown in the answers here is safer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
DataRow row = ...

var values = from DataColumn column in row.Table.Columns
             where column.ColumnName.StartsWith("FK")
             select Convert.ToString(row[column]);

var valueArray = values.ToArray();
```

If you want the result as a map instead, you can do:

```
var result = row.Table
                .Columns
                .Cast<DataColumn>()
                .Where(column => column.ColumnName.StartsWith("FK"))
                .ToDictionary(column => column.ColumnName,
                              column => Convert.ToString(row[column]));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("FKStuff");
dt.Columns.Add("OtherStuff");
dt.Columns.Add("FKAndMoreStuff");

var row = dt.Rows.Add("ABC", "DEF", "GHI");
var vals = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where(c => c.ColumnName.StartsWith("FK")).Select(col => row[col]).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use this:

```
var values = row.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                .Where(x => x.ColumnName.StartsWith("FK"))
                .Select(x => row[x].ToString())
                .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var sa = (from DataColumn x in row.Table.Columns
          where x.ColumnName.StartsWith("FK")
          select row[x].ToString()).ToArray();
```

The logic here is to get a sequence of those columns whose names start with "FK", then for each of those, to select the row value at that column, convert it to string, then make an array out of the result. If you don't need an actual array, then leave off the `.ToArray()` and the extra set of parentheses.